# Better music playlists management on YouTube

Tags: music, youtube

As many people, I manage the music I listen to using YouTube playlists. I have quite a lot of them now, but I see unsolved problems regarding them. The main one is that quite often some music videos disappears from YouTube. In such cases I am not able to get to know what titles were removed, often even though other versions of this song (even the official ones) are still available. Another problem is the matter of duplicates - quite often I find a song I already have on some of my playlists, but I can't check it easily, because I have another version (I mean: the same music, but with other video). Is there some app that could help me with these problems, or at least one of them?

Comment: Perhaps you can find some useful information [in this Q&A](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/27589).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [YouTube Music](https://music.youtube.com), it has a better playlist management system.